# Create a new file and insert a value in a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I use the following VBA to create a new file from an existing file:

```
Sub Files()
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\testfile.xlsm"
  Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\" & "testfile.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=False
  ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges = False
End Sub
```

After the file is created the new file is opened and the original file is closed. 
All this works fine so far.

---

However, now I want to that in the new file the number `1` is inserted into `Cell A1` of the `first sheet`. Basically, something like this:

```
Sub InsertValue
Sheet1 (in new created file).Range("A1").Value = 1
End Sub
```

How do I have to modify my code to make this work?

I thought about including the file path of the new created file in the `Sub InsertValue` and then `Call` this sub before `ThisWorkbook.Close` but I could not make it work so far :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Files()
    Dim wb As Workbook, newWb As Workbook, path As String
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    path = "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\testfile.xlsm"

    wb.SaveCopyAs path
    Set newWb = Workbooks.Open(path, UpdateLinks:=False)

    newWb.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value = 1
    wb.Close (False)
End Sub
```

It based on references - hold references to workbooks in variables and use them further in code to set for example value in cell in sheet in new workbook :)

The last thing you call is closing old workbook, because it terminates also a code :)

Comment: Thanks for the answert. It works great. However, do you also know a solution if I want to refer to the internal sheet name (according to the object catalogue) instead of Sheets(1). I tried to go with newWb.Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = 1 but get runtime error 438.

Comment: @Michi Sure, just use `Sheets("Sheet1")`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't save any changes in the original you can just change the value in that, save a copy and then throw the original away

```
Sub Files()
  Activeworkbook.sheets(1).range("A1") = 1
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\testfile.xlsm"
  Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\" & "testfile.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=False
  ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges = False
End Sub
```